# Closing connections in Spring DATA jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I am using spring data jpa and hikari connection pooling. In repository file, I am using methods to connect to database. I would like to know how and where to close the database connections.

```
Repository
public interface abc extends JPARepository<abc, int>{

List<abc> findById(int id);}
```

Any help on how to close the connections and where(service layer or repository) would be really appreciated

`

Comment: You don't have to take care of that

Comment: With framework, The task of creating a connection before each operation and closing the connection after the operation is now taken from the programmer and transferred to the Spring Context. Code duplication is minimized

Comment: I am getting this exception->Connection is not available, request timed out after x ms. Unable to acquire jdbc connection......I have changed the properties too(namely maximum pool size, idle timeout etc.) but still getting the exception

Comment: This can have various reasons; you'll have to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: You can provide errors, and code snippet as in what all you have used ad what exactly is causing this error from logs.

Answer (score 1):

**With Connection Pooling**, using the framework, The task of creating a connection before each operation and closing the connection after the operation is now taken from the programmer and transferred to the Spring Context:-

The application requests a connection from the connection pool.
If an unused connection exists, it is returned by the pool; otherwise, the pool creates a new connection.
The application sends a query to the Hybrid Data Pipeline connectivity service.
The application obtains query results.
The application displays the result to the end-user.
The application closes the connection, which returns the connection to the pool.

Note: The application calls the close() method, which allows the connection to remain open. The pool receives the notification of the close request.